# DRF - Get not allowed

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have the following function (showing imports just for the sake of completeness):

```
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken


class RefreshAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request):
        key = request.query_params.get('auth_token').strip()
        try:
            token = self.model.objects.get(key=key)
            token.delete()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=serializer.object['user'])
            token.created = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
            token.save()
            return Response({'token': token.key})
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return Response("Error", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I visit the url with **/?auth_token=619f853ac32e171facb3068c990c6eded81a59c9**, I get an error:

```
{"detail":"Method \"GET\" not allowed."}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you need to set existed token key, not blablabla

Comment: I have an existing key.

Comment: and this key value is blablabla ?

Comment: When I log in, I copy paste they key response: 619f853ac32e171facb3068c990c6eded81a59c9. Will edit my question to eliminate confusion

Comment: key = request.query_params.get('auth_token').strip() and maybe you need to change it into key = request.query_params.get('api_token').strip()

Comment: nope, ant apologies, modified my question on that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should request via POST or change the function name to get.

Comment: Is that a right thing to do? I am modifying info, so it is a post request.

Comment: Yes, there is only a method named post, so It just can handle post request. If you want to request via GET or PUT or other methods, you should add a method named get or put.